# Проблема с ботом instaPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, instapy

Выдаёт ошибки:

```
 File "C:\Users\ILYA558\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "C:\Users\ILYA558\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 131, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser.install_addon(create_firefox_extension(), temporary=True)
  File "C:\Users\ILYA558\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 48, in create_firefox_extension
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zipf:
  File "C:\Users\ILYA558\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\ILYA558\\InstaPy\\assets\\extension.xpi'
```

Вот код:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username = "theworldplaytop", password = "тут пароль мой", headless_browser = True)
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled = True, max_followers = 200)

session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=100)
session.like_by_tags(["minecraft", "майнкрафт"], amount = 3)
session.set_dont_like(["nsfw"])

session.unfollow_users(amount=6, aLLFollowing=True, sleep_delay=60)
session.end
```

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка у InstaPy возникает, когда он не может работать с заданным файлом, по причине того, что он уже занят другим процессом. У меня такая ситуация возникает при создании мультиакков с помощью потоков, ведь они ссылаются на один файл, а он занят первым потоком. Самому хотелось бы узнать, как решить.